# View a remote Ubuntu desktop from Windows 7

Tags: vnc, remote-desktop, nx

I tried TightVNC and VNC Viewer (realvnc), and they both show checkboard screens (no screen only checkboard). Also, I tried RDP, same result: checkboard screen.

I tried FreeNX, but I would like **stronger/better compression** since I have very fast CPUs on both client and server (though the RAM on the server is only 512MB burstable to 1GB). So, I have the processing power, and I want to take advantage of that to make the connection seamless.

Comment: Do you need X-forwarding, like remote-desktop? If you need only access to a shell on your Ubuntu box, I recommend [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) on your Windows box.

Comment: Yes, I want to control the desktop (like in FreeNX)

Comment: Just googled it: tried using [remote desktop w. xrdp](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2011/06/connect-to-ubuntu-11-04-from-windows-via-remote-desktop/)?

Comment: It gives checkboard screen, I can't see anything, only white&black net of boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Xvnc runs its own X server, which is not necessarily connected to the desktop. You'd need to run either the vnc X extension or vino if you want to connect to the main desktop with VNC.